# Laravel: How to merge 2 different database queries into one and access the results?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to retrieve the total and the number of user likes in a post from the database.

Right now, I'm sending 2 different queries and retrieving the results.

But I would like to merge both queries into one and get the results from one database request only.

This is what I tried:

```php
$userId = auth('sanctum')->user()->id;

$userLikesCountQuery = DB::table("likes")
    ->select('SUM(like) as user_count')
    ->where('user_id', $userId);

$data = DB::table("likes")
    ->select(
        DB::raw('SUM(like) as count'),
        $userLikesCountQuery,
    )
    ->first();

return [
   'meta' => [
        'count' => $data->count ?? 0,
        'user_count' => $data->user_count ?? 0,
   ],
];
```

This is resulting in the following error: `stripos(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string, Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder given`

Laravel does something similar when eager loading relationships with Eloquent.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In the end it will still run two separate queries, there is no need to merge them and would be more maintainable if you got them separately.

```
$user = auth('sanctum')->user();

$count = Like::sum('like');
$userCount = $user->likes()->sum('like');

return [
   'meta' => [
        'count' => $count,
        'user_count' => $userCount,
   ],
];
```